# UICollectionView Crashes on iOS 7

Tags: ios, crash, uicollectionview

I have an app that shows the newest 50 images from a Flickr photo stream in a collection view. It works fine on iOS 6 but crashes on iOS 7. If I uninstall the app and reinstall it, it works fine the first time I load that view. When i back out of that view and then go back to it, it crashes. Any ideas?

This is the error I get:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'too many update animations on one view - limit is 15 in flight at a time (; }; layer = >)'

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#import "KFBFlickrPhotoManager.h"
#import "KFBImageDetailViewController.h"

@interface KFBFlickrViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,FlickrPhotoDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{

    NSMutableArray *imageInfo;
}

@property (retain) NSMutableArray * imageInfo;
@property (retain) KFBFlickrPhotoManager * imageManager;
@property (retain) NSString * html;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *apiKey;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *photoCollectionView;
@property (retain) KFBImageDetailViewController *imageDetailViewController;
@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "KFBFlickrViewController.h"
#import "KFBFlickrPhoto.h"

@interface KFBFlickrViewController ()

@end

@implementation KFBFlickrViewController

@synthesize apiKey=apiKey;
@synthesize photoCollectionView, imageManager, imageInfo,imageDetailViewController;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        apiKey = @"a70fe2e828e66660c74ce0a7c34a55aa";
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=%@&per_page=50&user_id=52540720@N02&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", apiKey];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        imageInfo = [NSMutableArray array];

        self.imageInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.imageManager = [[KFBFlickrPhotoManager alloc] initWithURL:url delegate:self];
        [imageManager process];


        imageInfo = [NSMutableArray array];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(imageUpdated:) name:@"com.KFB.imageupdated" object:nil];
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(imageUpdated:) name:@"com.KFB.imageupdated" object:nil];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"com.razeware.imagegrabber.imageupdated" object:nil];
}

-(void)showFlickr
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.kyfb.com/photos"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Photos";
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CVCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.photoCollectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell"];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(75, 75)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    [flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
    [self.photoCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    UIBarButtonItem *openFlickr = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"More Photos" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showFlickr)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = openFlickr;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"photoCell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    KFBFlickrPhoto * info = [imageInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:2020];
    imageView.image = info.image;

    return cell;
}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    KFBFlickrPhoto *photo = [imageInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.imageDetailViewController = [[KFBImageDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KFBImageDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    imageDetailViewController.photo = photo;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:imageDetailViewController animated:YES];
}


-(void)imagesAvailable:(NSArray *)images done:(BOOL)done {

    NSLog(@"Image infos available: %d!", images.count);

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:images.count];
    for(int i = imageInfo.count; i < imageInfo.count + images.count; ++i) {
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [imageInfo addObjectsFromArray:images];
    [photoCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
    //[photoCollectionView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

}


- (void)imageUpdated:(NSNotification *)notif {

    UIImage *info = [notif object];
    int row = [imageInfo indexOfObject:info];
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];

    NSLog(@"Image for row %d updated!", row);
    [photoCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
    //[photoCollectionView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [imageInfo count];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your UICollectionView?

Comment: I've added the code for the collection view

Comment: Try this: In your -(void)imagesAvailable:(NSArray *)images done:(BOOL)done method, limit the call to [photoCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths]; to at most 15 images at a time. I think you are getting the error due to the [photoCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths]; call when indexPaths.count >15.

Comment: How would I limit it to only do 15 at a time?

Answer (score 1):

After doing a little research I think a better approach would be to try the performBatchUpdates:completion: method of UICollectionView. Your method would end-up looking something like this:

```
-(void)imagesAvailable:(NSArray *)images done:(BOOL)done {

[photoCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    NSLog(@"Image infos available: %d!", images.count);

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:images.count];
    for(int i = imageInfo.count; i < imageInfo.count + images.count; ++i) {
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [imageInfo addObjectsFromArray:images];
    [photoCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
} completion:nil];

}
```

See [SO question on UICollectionView updates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12656648/35499) for more details.

Comment: Using that code works the first time you open that view, but every time you try to go to it again, it crashes.  The only way to get it to work again is to uninstall the app and reinstall it.  I don't get the same error though.  On the line [photoCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]]; it says Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

Comment: Any ideas about that?