# UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath not called after numberOfItemsInSection returns nonzero item number

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

Is there any reason that `cellForItemAtIndexPath` would not get called after `numberOfItemsInSection` gets called and returns a nonzero number? Would a `reloadData` from a completion block affect this? I'm running into an issue in which I am trying to delete a cell through a `UIAlertController` and the UI looks great, but when I go to `reloadData` after the UI animation finishes `numberOfItemsInSection` properly gets called with the right number of elements (the previous number of elements minus 1), yet `cellForItemAtIndexPath` does not get called, so my cells don't get reloaded. Any ideas as to why this would happen?

This is on `Swift 1.2`, `XCode 6.4`, and any help would be greatly appreciated

Just to give a bit more information, the method I'm using to delete a cell is looking a little like:

```
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    let indexPathCellToDelete = self.indexPath(feedCell)
    self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPathCellToDelete])
}, completion:nil)
```

Would having a second reload in the completion block change anything?

Comment: Did you hook up the delegate and datasource correctly?

Comment: Absolutely, all the data is properly showing up normally before I delete something, it's only after deleting an item in the collection view that the method is no longer called

Comment: Try reloading on the main thread.

Comment: Tried it, did not work. So it's not a main queue issue

Comment: Can you manually try calling `cellForItemAtIndexPath`?

Comment: What would that accomplish? That's counter productive it would seem

Comment: Just to make sure that it can be called.

Comment: It is obviously called before the deletion, adding a call afterwards is useless, and doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: After performBatchUpdates, why should the collection view need to create new cells? All you've done is delete a cell. The other cells still exist; it doesn't need to re-create them.  (I don't see a call to reloadData anywhere, which would trigger the cells to be re-created).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `performBatchUpdates`, according to [UICollectionView Performing Updates using performBatchUpdates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656648/uicollectionview-performing-updates-using-performbatchupdates) needs to be called after the change to my data source has been done. The issue was, though, that my method for deleting an item from my data source itself reloads the collection view, so there was an extra reload that did not need to happen, which was causing the issue, it seems. I initially had the call to my data source deletion method in the completion block of the `performBatchUpdates`,  but moving that above and just reloading the entire collection view seems to have solved the issue. Seems like a weird race condition in my case where there are multiple reloads happening simultaneously and `cellForItemAtIndexPath` didn't like that.